# Tensorflow runtime error debug

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

How to debug a runtime error in Tensorflow?

I am new to tensorflow and would appreciate any help. I am executing a code and after executing the line sess.run() it throws an error. I am using Tensorflow 1.0 and python 3.5.2

Below is the snippet of error:

```
INFO:tensorflow:starting run_training
INFO:tensorflow:running training step...
F c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\tensor.h:582] Check failed: new_num_elements == NumElements() (160 vs. 81920)
```

I believe the error with values (160 vs. 81920) is due to some variable being initialized with 160 values and now 81920 values are passed to it. But I am not able to zero down on which exact tensor it is. There is now line number or any clue mentioned in the error.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I dont have enough credit to post this as a comment

You better add the code in the question or the good people of this great community will devote you out of here.

Comment: I second this. We can't help if you don't show us code.